# Can you recommend me a book on the discoveries and properties of these particles?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good book about elementary particles for high school students?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9389/good-book-about-elementary-particles-for-high-school-students)

Some days ago, I've found this:

[image]

When I was in high-school, They taught me about electrons, protons and neutrons, I've heard about other particles while reading stuff but I've read only their name, not their properties.

I got curious about them and then I thought about searching a book (It could be something like a pop science book) with commentaries on the discovery and properties of these particles.

Comment: Oh groan, that just does not look right!   Quarks can't be said to have been established until some crucial experiments in the 70s and Gell-Mann's theory.  I'm not sure either concept or experimental discovery belongs in the 1960s.

Comment: @DarenW It was clear by the mid 1960s that there was a substructure to the nucleon and the excitations of that structure were possible, which may be the motivation for choosing that time frames as the "conception" for the light quarks.